# LibGDX FrameBuffer

Tags: libgdx

I'm trying to make a game where you build a spaceship from parts, and fly it around and such.

I would like to create the ship from a series of components (from a TextureAtlas for instance).  I'd like to draw the ship from it's component textures, and then save the drawn ship as one large Texture. (So i don't have to draw 50 component textures, just one ship texture. What would be the best way to go about this?

I've been trying to do so using a FrameBuffer.  I've been able to draw the components to a Texture, and draw the texture to the screen, but no matter what I try the Texture ends up with a solid background the size of the frame buffer. It's like the clear command can't clear with transparency. Here's the drawing code I have at the moment. The ship is just a Sprite which i save the FrameBuffer texture to.

```java
public void render(){

    if (ship == null){
        int screenwidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        int screenheight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

        SpriteBatch fb = new SpriteBatch();

        FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB888, screenwidth, screenheight, false);

        fbo.begin();

        fb.enableBlending();
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFuncSeparate(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 1, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        fb.begin();

        atlas.createSprite("0").draw(fb);

        fb.end();

        fbo.end();

        ship = new Sprite(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
        ship.setPosition(0, -screenheight);
    }

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.begin();

    batch.enableBlending();
    batch.setBlendFunction(GL20.GL_ONE, GL20.GL_ZERO);
    ship.draw(batch);
    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `PixMap` but i never used it myself, look for a tutorial of it!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem here lies in this line:

```
 FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGB888, screenwidth, screenheight, false);
```

specifically with `Format.RGB888`. This line is saying that your FrameBuffer should be **Red** (8 bits) followed by **Green** (8 bits) followed by **Blue** (8 bits). Notice however, that this format doesn't have any bits for **Alpha** (transparency). In order to get transparency out of your frame buffer, you probably instead want to use the `Format.RGBA8888`, which includes an additional 8 bits for Alpha.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I though 888 was pertaining to something to do with the alpha. So you also informed me how formats are described. Thanks!