# Embed JOGL or LibGDX in JavaFX 2020

Tags: java, javafx, libgdx

I've searched around for ways of embedding a JOGL or LibGDX app within a JavaFX App.

The only results are from 2014 or older.  I've tried them out, but it looks like they don't work with the modern LibGDX.

https://bitbucket.org/xpenatan/libgdx-javafx/src/master/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/

https://github.com/Trixt0r/LibGDX-FX

And as for JOGL, there is talk since 2012 of waiting for something like JavaFX PixelBuffer so I'm hoping there is some work going on there.

My main goal is to use JavaFX for the buttons and rest of its controls, and JOGL or LibGDX as a single window inside.  I don't wish to use LibGDX scene.ui because it is not nearly as nice as JavaFX IMO.

Is there a way to take the LibGDX framebuffer and render it to a JavaFX canvas?

It looks like these guys figured out a way using JavaFX PixelBuffer, but they use C++ instead of JOGL or LibGDX.

https://github.com/miho/NativeFX

https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-drift/

It looks like they have some sort of JavaFX and JOGL interop [here](https://github.com/sgothel/jogl/blob/fc2edeb79e42897b926081769ad3cb3e509aed71/src/test/com/jogamp/opengl/test/junit/jogl/javafx/TestNewtCanvasJFXGLn.java) using NewtCanvasJFX. But I don't think it has been released.

Comment: Rendering it to a JavaFX Canvas is not the right strategy. What you would need is a way to configure libGDX to render into a memory buffer. Once you have that I could provide a solution which I have cooking at the moment. Its based on the new native image support in JavaFX 13.

Comment: @mipa There is use of a framebuffer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434236/libgdx-framebuffer would that work? That and running LibGDX in headless mode may provide some guidance. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/backends/gdx-backend-headless/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/headless

Comment: I think this link is closer to what I'd need. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/102615/how-to-store-each-rendered-frame-as-image-in-libgdx-for-debugging Especially ScreenUtils.getFrameBufferPixmap(x, y, w, h).getPixels() would provide exactly what I would need, but I don't know whether this is performant enuough.

Comment: @mipa Give it a shot! Seems simple enough, but not sure about the other code you are writing.

Comment: I don't have the time to do that shooting for you :-) but I have uploaded a demo how this could be done to my GitHub account. https://github.com/mipastgt/JFXToolsAndDemos The most relevant demo is called NativeRenderingCanvas although in your case it is not really native but conceptually this does not make a difference.

Comment: Any news about it ?