# Unable to load Attribute into shader

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, glsl

I would like to have some custom data stored inside the shader to be re-used for multiple frame during rendering. 
At first what I try to do is to store a color buffer, to see is this can be done.

**vertex shader:**

```c
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;

uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;
attribute vec3 my_data;
varying vec3 frag_data;

void main() {
    v_color = a_color;
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    frag_data = my_data;
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```c
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

varying vec3 frag_data;

void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(frag_data),1.0);
}
```

The shaders compile and work as intended with the exception of the usage of `vec3 my_data`:

```java
        ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
        vertex_shader = Gdx.files.internal("vertex_shader.glsl").readString();
        fragment_shader = Gdx.files.internal("fragment_shader.glsl").readString();
        shader_program = new ShaderProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
```

I try to set the variable from a button-click, like so:

```java
        goBtn = new TextButton("Reset", textButtonStyle);
        goBtn.setSize(128,128);
        goBtn.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                FloatBuffer myArray = BufferUtils.newFloatBuffer(3);
                myArray.put(1.0f);myArray.put(1.0f);myArray.put(1.0f);

                shader_program.begin();
                shader_program.setVertexAttribute("my_data", 3, GL20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, myArray);
                shader_program.end();
            }
        });
```

But it has no effect..

What am I doing wrong here?

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: You can't attach something from outside to a **varying**. You have to bind whatever you use to a **attribute** and pass that attribute to a varying as you already do with `a_color/v_color` and `a_texCoord0/v_texCoords`.

Comment: `varying` variables are interface variables between shader stages. You have to set `my_data` in the vertex shader. If you want an additional attribute then you have to use the keyword `attribute`

Comment: you are correct. I updated the shaders to reflect this. 
However there is still no effect to the push of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried setting a vertex attribute via the ShaderProgram. I'm not even sure why that exists as an option, because vertex data is supposed to be per-vertex. Since you are setting this for the whole mesh, it should be a uniform. And since it's a uniform, you don't have to pass it via a varying either.

So remove the varying and attribute from your vertex shader. And change the varying in the fragment shader to a uniform.

And to pass the data:

```
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            shader_program.begin();
            shader_program.setUniformf("my_data", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
            shader_program.end();
        }
```

But you should also call this code to set the default values for this uniform when you are first setting things up. Behavior might be undefined before you set their values.

Comment: Shouldn'1 uniform values be unchanges throughout the rendering steps? This is supposed to be something which is being modified from inside the shader.. would that still be valid?

Comment: If you're switching to a different shader for this one object, it will flush the batch anyway when you switch shaders. But anyway, you're changing the value in this listener, not during rendering.

Comment: That's true, and what you wrote made the program work. However, the whole reason I wanted to do this was to actually calculate the by-pixel operationson the GPU, and now when I try to modify it, the following error appears: `ERROR: 0:20: 'assign' : l-value required "my_data" (cannot modify a uniform)`

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're doing. If it's just a constant that can be used to calculate a per-fragment value, you can copy it to a variable in the `main` function and modify the copy. `vec3 localFragData = frag_data;

Comment: it's supposed to be calculating a per-pixel value, but it isn't supposed to be constant, the GPU cores would modify it, basically it would act like a [vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field)

Comment: After further investigation, I think I can pass data in through Vertex attributes, and then [render the result into a framebuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24434236/libgdx-framebuffer), which I can pass back in the next loop as a vertex attribute. In this sense I think I need to re-consider multiple design choices, but for the question I asked yours is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: OK. If you have a more specific description about what you're doing, you can post it as a question and I can take a look. I've done a lot of different types of shader effects in 2D and 3D, some with FrameBuffers and some without.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214175/discussion-between-david-toth-and-tenfour04).